# Using Node.js, make a new XMLHttpRequest during or after a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, web-crawler

I am very new to Node.js and XMLHttpRequest, so please bear with me if this is a question with a simple answer.

I am currently trying to crawl a friends webpage (with his permission of course) which hosts videos and subtitles. I want to do this by writing a Node.js command line application. Currently, I am just trying to get to the link of the video and the link to subtitle. This is what I have so far:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    // HTML source
    var html = this.responseText;
    var season = 0;
    var episode = 0;

    var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
      onopentag: function(name, attribs) {
        if (name === "li" && attribs.id === "season-1") {
          season = 1;
          console.log("In season 1");
          for(var attr in attribs){
            console.log(attr);
          }
        }
        if (name === "a" && season === 1) {
          episode = 1;
          var nextPage = attribs.data;
          console.log("\""+nextPage+"\"");

          // Go to "nextPage" here
          xhttp.open("GET", "\""+nextPage+"\"", true);

        }
      },
      onattribute: function(name, value) {
        if(name === "data-url" && season === 1){
          if(value.includes("episode-")){
            episode = value.substr(8,1);
          }
          console.log(value);
          console.log("Episode is: " + episode)
        }
      },
      ontext: function(text) {

      },
      onclosetag: function(tagname) {
        if (tagname === "li" && season === 1) {
          season = 0;
          console.log("Leaving season 1");
        }
      }
    }, {
      decodeEntities: true
    });
    parser.write(html);
    parser.end();

  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://friendspage.org", true);
xhttp.send();
```

The code above results in this output:

```
In season 1
id
episode-1
Episode is: 1
"https://friendspage.org/episode-1"
episode-2
Episode is: 2
"https://friendspage.org/episode-2"
episode-3
Episode is: 3
"https://friendspage.org/episode-3"
episode-4
Episode is: 4
"https://friendspage.org/episode-4"
episode-5
Episode is: 5
"https://friendspage.org/episode-5"
episode-6
Episode is: 6
"https://friendspage.org/episode-6"
episode-7
Episode is: 7
"https://friendspage.org/episode-7"
episode-8
Episode is: 8
"https://friendspage.org/episode-8"
episode-9
Episode is: 9
"https://friendspage.org/episode-9"
Leaving season 1
```

The code works as I want it to, except for the part where I want to go to the `nextPage`. I am going to use input variables from the command line to choose which page to go to, but currently, I don't know how to go to the `nextPage`.

```js
// Go to "nextPage" here
xhttp.open("GET", "\""+nextPage+"\"", true);
```

Trying to use `xhttp.send()` results in an error `send has already been called`. I am guessing I either need to close the current request and open a new one, or simply start another instance of XMLHttpRequest.

If that is what I would need to do, which is the preferred method? And what would be the cleanest way to do it? If not, what is the solution I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new xhttp object in a new variable for each new request. Don't reuse the current one.

FYI, the `request-promise` library is much better built for node.js than trying to emulate an archaic interface from the browser (which even it has replaced with `fetch()`).  The functionality built into node.js to do this is `http.get()`, but that has been extended in a very helpful fashion in the `request` library and then it's been promisified in the `request-promise` library which makes it even easier to use.  I would strongly suggest using the request-promise library for this task.

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into request-promise. It looks very promising! :) .... Sorry, terrible pun xD

Comment: How would I use request-promise to go to nextPage? That is how do I make a new request? It is not part of the [GitHub cheat sheet](https://github.com/request/request-promise#cheat-sheet)

Comment: @Skillzore - You just call `rp('http://someURL').then(...)` to start a new request.

Comment: Well, I am currently using [the crawl a webpage better](https://github.com/request/request-promise#crawl-a-webpage-better) example. So do I just do another `var options` thing inside the first `then(function ($) {...})`? That doesn't seem very elegant....

Comment: @Skillzore - I can't debug code I can't see and I think we've already answered the original question you asked.  If you have a new question, perhaps you should post the exact code that the question is about in a new question.  If you want to call `rp()` with the same options in several different places, you can just make a local function that you pass the URL to and it creates the options you want and then calls `rp()` returning the promise.  That's just factoring common code into a shared function.

Comment: Sorry, made a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073931/best-method-of-moving-to-a-new-page-with-request-promise)