# Best method of moving to a new page with request-promise?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, request-promise

I am tinkering around with request-promise to crawl a friends webpage. I am using the [crawl a webpage better](https://github.com/request/request-promise#crawl-a-webpage-better) example on their GitHub. What I have so far is this:

```js
var rp = require('request-promise');
var cheerio = require('cheerio'); // Basically jQuery for node.js

var options = {
  uri: 'https://friendspage.org',
  transform: function(body) {
    return cheerio.load(body);
  }
};

rp(options)
  .then(function($) {
    // Process html like you would with jQuery...
    var nxtPage = $("a[data-url$='nxtPageId']").attr('data');

    // How do I use nxtPage here to go to that site

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // Crawling failed or Cheerio choked...
  });
```

What is the proper way to go to the link I have in `nxtPage`? I still want to be able to use cheerio/jQuery on it. Do I need to repeat the whole `var option = ...` thing inside the current `then` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create your own utility function that creates your options and then calls `rp()` like this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); // Basically jQuery for node.js

// shared function
function getPage(url) {
    const options = {
        uri: url,
        transform: function(body) {
          return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };
    return rp(options);
}

getPage('https://friendspage.org').then($ => {
    // Process html like you would with jQuery...
    const nxtPage = $("a[data-url$='nxtPageId']").attr('data');
    return getPage(nxtPage).then($ => {
        // more processing here
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    // error handling here
});
```

This is just factoring code that you want to use in multiple places into a shared function.  Nothing in particular to do with `rp()` or `cheerio`, just regular code factoring in Javascript (or any language).

Comment: This is great! I tried creating a method but kept getting solutions with the possibility of infinite loops, much like Aditya's answer here. Should probably have mentioned that in the question. I simply couldn't find this solution. My inexperience with promises and javascript is surely the reason for this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I wanted to clean up my code by refactoring it into functions, but when putting `const nxtPage = $("a[data-url$='nxtPageId']").attr('data');` into a function and calling it I get `$ is undefined`. I tried passing $ into the function, but then I get even weirder errors. How do I put $ into a separate function?

Comment: @Skillzore - Well, if you're going to put that into a function, you will have to pass `$` to that function.  It's not a global, it's the resolved value of the promise that `getPage()`.

Comment: Well, when passing $ to the function I get "option.uri is not defined". Like it is stripped of the set up made in `getPage()`. I am probably passing it wrong since I am so new to Javascript.

Comment: @Skillzore - I think I've answered the question you originally answered.  I can't debug code I can't see.  If you want help with how you're refactoring your code, then you can post a new question, show that new code in the question and ask a specific question about where you need help.

Comment: New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150702/how-to-make-cheerios-accessible-in-helper-functions-in-a-clean-way

Answer (score 0):

Wrap inside a function and keep calling it with a condition so recursion breaks at some time.

```
(function repeatUntilAConditionIsMetInThen(uri = 'https://friendspage.org')
  var options = {
    uri,
    transform: function(body) {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
  };
  rp(options)
    .then(function($) {
      var nxtPage = $("a[data-url$='nxtPageId']").attr('data');
      //There should be some condition here otherwise it will be infinite loop
      repeatUntilAConditionIsMetInThen(nxtPage);
    })
   .catch(function(err) {
   });
})();
```

Comment: I actually already thought of this solution (I should have stated it in the question) and felt that it was somewhat lacking. The risk of infinite loops is never a good thing. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: But what you have accepted in answer is something that runs one step ahead. It seemed as if yoh want to recursively go to nxt pzge till tne time you find it

Comment: I just wanted to get to the next page really. In an elegant way. I guess I am not really "crawling" the page, I know exactly where I want to go. I am really just automating a process for myself.